# Running series of commands in one command line, cmd

Tags: java, cmd

We've been trying to run successive commands in one command prompt using JAVA.

```
Process process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd c:\\program files (x86) && cd google && cd chrome && cd application");
```

What I'm hoping is that it will do `cd c:\\program files (x86)` first, then `cd google` then `cd chrome` then `cd application`.

When I run the code, it just opens the cmd and does the first command which is `cd c:\\program files (x86)`.

I know you can do it `cd c:\\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application`, but I am using this as test because my actual command lines are client specific, so I cannot use that as an example.

So basically, I need to run a series of command lines in succession.

Answer (score 0):

in your case I suppose the problem is with the shell command `cd c:\\program files (x86)`. It's the space between the words `program`, `files` and `(x86)` you should quote the string.

I suggest to execute your command first directly in a command line and see if happens what you want:

```
cmd.exe /c start cd "c:\\program files (x86)" && cd google && cd chrome && cd application
```

Answer (score 0):

you should qoute the strings and try to use this

```
Process process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd c:\\program%files%(x86) && cd google && cd chrome && cd application");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `start`. Place `""` around all paths. Replace `&&` by one escaped `&` like `^&` each. Like:

```cmd
cmd.exe /C cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)" ^& cd "google" ^& cd "chrome" ^& cd "application"
```

So:

```java
Process process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /C cd /D \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\" ^& cd \"google\" ^& cd \"chrome\" ^& cd \"application\"");
```